How jvm implements interface polymorphism internally
I would like to understand how jvm make interface method polymorphic (when invoked from interface reference).
I have read an article about how jvm make polymorphism work for classes inheritance, by having the superclass object having two pointer, one reference to the object data and another to the vtable of the class, and how the method override the superclass method in the vtable.
thanks

You should forget about that two pointers things quickly. This cite has been taken out of context and does not apply to any real JVM of the last two decades.
